# How to use Mat_ template in swig?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, swig, opencv, python

So I have an `.hpp` file that I'm planning to use in swig, but said file has a template (`Mat_<float>` to be exact), but whenever I run `swig` I end up getting:

```
example.hpp::30: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

With line 30 being:

```
Mat_<float> measurement(8,1);
```

I'm not very familiar with c++ (and using `cv2` for this one particular project isn't really possible), and from what I've found I need to define the template in my .i file, but looking through the examples, I wasn't quite sure how I should go about doing that. Any help?

My .i file:

```
%module example

%include <opencv.i>
%cv_instantiate_all_defaults

%{
    #include "example.hpp"
%}

%include "example.hpp"
```

(I'm using [opencv-swig](https://github.com/renatoGarcia/opencv-swig) for the OpenCV part)

Commands for compiling/building:

```
swig -I/home/me/Documents/.../opencv-swig/lib/ -I/usr/include -python -c++ example.i

g++ -shared -std=c++1z -fpic example_wrap.cxx $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) $(pkg-config --libs opencv) -o _example.so
```

Comment: Can you share more of your `file.hpp` file ? And is it the same file as `example.hpp` ?

Comment: @Fifi Oh my bad, they're the same file, and file/example were just placeholder names. Edited.

Comment: Did you try without the line 30 ? I already had the same error message and it was not related to the indicated line, but with a problem sooner

Comment: @Fifi Yup. I am 100% sure it's just a matter of defining the template.

Comment: And does it work with an other type ? (Like `Mat_<double>` for example)

Comment: @Fifi No, it just doesn't work in general. And from what I've gathered, it comes from using a template, and said template needs to be defined in the .i file, however, despite looking at the documentation, I wasn't quite sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Maybe you can try to open an issue in the github of opencv-swig.

Answer (score 1):

[Swig documentation on templates](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nn30)

You might need to use something like
`%template(Mat_float_) Mat_<float>;` at the end of your .i file.